# How to find the maximum sum of a subsequence of maximum length

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm working on an interview question for which I couldn't find any textbook solution for. Given a list of integers, find the maximum sum of any consecutive values / sublist no longer than a given K length.

Comment: Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? 
Show your effort first so people might show theirs. 
Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) center as a start.

Comment: @idstam I've tried 2 variations of a quadratic solution but I'm hoping to find a linear time solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let p[i] be the prefix sum a[0] + ... + a[i - 1]. We can compute the sequence p easily in linear time. For a fixed index i, the maximum sum of a subarray of size at most K that has its right boundary at index i can be computed as

MAX(j = max(0, i - K + 1) to i, p[i + 1] - p[j]) = p[i + 1] - MIN(j = max(0, i - K + 1) to i, p[j])

We can process the possible right borders i in ascending order. We then want to compute for each such i the MIN term in the above formula in O(1). This is exactly the [sliding window minimum](http://people.cs.uct.ac.za/~ksmith/articles/sliding_window_minimum.html) problem, which has a nice solution using a special queue data structure. This queue supports the operations *push*/*pop* as well as *min* in amortized O(1). Using it, our algorithm looks like this:

```py
q = new MinQueue()
sum = 0
answer = 0
for i := 0 to N - 1:
    q.push(sum)  # sum == p[i]
    if len(q) > K:
        q.pop()
    sum += a[i]
    answer = max(answer, sum - q.min())  # sum == p[i + 1]
```

The total runtime is linear.

Comment: Hi @Niklas, I've implemented your solution here: http://repl.it/dw8/1, even though the queue does not have O(1) `min`. The expected answer is 9, why is it giving 10? Did I get something wrong somewhere?

Comment: @paranoid-android You are using `pop()` on a deque, which pops from the right. You should use `popleft()` instead. FWIW, here's an implementation of the min-queue in C++: https://github.com/niklasb/contest-algos/blob/master/monotonic_queue.cpp

Comment: This is very informative thank you very much. However, it doesn't currently catch the case where all values in the list are negative.

Comment: @paranoid-android Why not? The answer should be 0 in that case no? If not, just initialize answer to negative infinity

Comment: An array with all negatives will have the largest negative as the maximum subarray sum. Negative infinity should work I think, feel free to update your answer if you want.

Comment: @paranoid-android It's certainly a matter of definition. I consider the empty subarray as optimal in this case, with sum 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline. You have X[i, where i=1..N] numbers. Given K, assuming K <= N, there are N-K+1 sub-sequences, starting from 1..(N-K+1). You can store the sums in S[j, j=1..N-K+1]

Say, you already have S[j]. Then 
  S[j+1] = S[j] - X[j-1] + X[j+K-1]. 
You need to find S[1], and then the rest are simple. The problem now reduces to finding the largest value in S. There can be 1 or more answers. Complexity linear.

HTH get you started.

Comment: Actually the solution might be a subarray smaller than K

Comment: E.g. K = 2, a = [-1, -1, 1, -1]

Comment: Indeed, but my understanding is that K must be observed.

Comment: ..continuing..Otherwise (and that's a very interesting problem, thank you), generalizing your hunt for negatives at ends -- the largest sub-subsequence at either ends that results in a -ve sum could be discarded and process repeated (for each subsequence) until there was no more discards (wondering if a single discard will suffice - any thoughts?)

Comment: quote: "no longer than a given K" The greedy approach you describe is obviously correct, but it doesn't yield a fast algorithm

Answer (score 0):

It looks similar to maximum subarray problem. refer  _http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem_

```
var arr = [1,2,31,24,34,3,23,24,3,25,34,54,3,2,34];
var getSmallestSubSeqSum = function(arr, k){
    var totalLength = arr.length, index = 0, sums= [];
    for(index=0;index < totalLength-k+1;index++)
    {
        sums.push(0);
    }

    for(var index=0; index < totalLength-k+1;index++)
    {
        for(var aI = 0; aI < k; aI++)
        {
            sums[index] += arr[index + aI];
        }
    }
    console.log('Total Length: ' + totalLength);
    console.log('Sub Length: ' + 3);    
    console.log('sums length: ' + sums.length);
    console.log("Array: "+arr);

    index = Math.max.apply(Math, sums);
    console.log('Max Sum: ' + index);
    console.log("Sums: "+ sums);

    index = sums.indexOf(index);
    console.log("max sum sub array: " + arr.slice(index, index + k));
};

getSmallestSubSeqSum(arr, 6);
```

The above code snippet should help this is javascript.

Comment: this is rather inefficient in computing sum[index]. Please see my answer at bottom

Answer (score 0):

The N numbers are X[0],...X[N-1] and assuming 1<=K<=N. S[i,l] stands for the maximum sum of the sublist that starts from i and has no more than l length.

You have S[i,1] = X[i] and then S[i,l] = MAX(S[i+1, l-1]+X[i], X[i]), where l>=2.

The final answer is MAX(S[i,K], where i<=N-1 and i>=0).

Comment: That's Omega(NK) however, although linear time is possible